# How can I prevent a dependency that is only available from other dependencies, from being used

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

TLDR - I refactored all our codebase to use lodash-es for its tree-shakeable capabilities. The problem is that occasionally I still find `import _ from 'lodash'` in our code/PRs even tho lodash is not a dependency in our project.

---

Is there a proper way to configure this project so that no one can access lodash? I don't have 'lodash' defined in my package.json. Only 'lodash-es'.

Using `npm ls lodash` shows a handful of matches. Not sure what to look for here.

---

```
yarn -v // 1.22.19
npm -v // 8.11.0
node -v // 16.16.0
```

Comment: You can try to alias it : "lodash": "npm:lodash-es@^x.y.z", Not sure if the exports match however between the two packages.

Comment: Tried adding this to my project and library but it doesn't work for some reason. Hovering 'lodash' still goes to '@types/lodash'. Tried adding the types as a path alias as well. I might end up using eslint to error this import out instead